# Are feral hog hind quarters hams, or a different type of pork?

Tags: pork, language, smoking, ham

I recently hunted feral hog and had one processed.  I have two full bone-in hind quarters.  I wondering if these are considered hams or a different cut/type of pork.  How would one go about cooking a full bone-in hind quarter?  What are the proper temperatures to cook feral hog to?  I would like to make a ham if possible, also maybe pulled pork or something else with the second hind quarter.  Thinking maybe in the smoker too.

Comment: Cuts differ from country to country. I looked at your profile, and you're from the US (Just stating it here, so that others do not have to search for it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They would be fresh hams, the hindquarter of a pig.

The word ham, unmodified, implies a cured product.

I would imagine that for a feral hog, if you are willing to risk eating it, that you should cook to the highest temperature reasonable, which in the case of a fresh ham might be at least 180 F, and as high as 200 F.  The best application at these ranges would be making puiled pork, which requires long, low, and slow cooking; smoking is definitely an option.

See also [this recipe](http://www.amazingribs.com/recipes/porknography/perfect_pulled_pork.html), although for a pork butt, should be easily adaptable to the fresh ham, which is similar, although not quite as fatty and full of connective tissue, so it won't be quite as tender when done.

Comment: Good answer, thanks for the info.  I was unsure exactly what a "ham" was.  I think I'll smoke these and then pull them.